# IS there a way to compile into a JAR even though errors occur

Tags: java, netbeans, compiler-construction

I am trying to compile a file into a .jar, but NetBeans won't let me compile it. Im getting errors that the `import` files are not on the computer. This is because I don't have them on my computer here. Is there a way I can force compile? I am using NetBeans 7.0.1 for Mac.

Comment: Seriously, find the missing dependencies and specify them on the project classpath.

Comment: @Perception I do not have them on this computer.

Comment: Then put them on that computer. Your question makes no sense, I'm afraid. "I have a problem that I know is caused because I'm missing something. Can I work without installing what I'm missing?".

Comment: @KenWhite Alright. Could I access it from a flash drive?

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot force the compile.  Without the import, the compiler does not have enough information to do the job.  If you are missing files, then you will need to locate them in order to do the compile.

Possible workarounds:

- find a pre-compiled version of the file and use that
- remove the import statement and any code that references it